# Setup .fxml file programmatically

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I am used to writing code in JavaFx like the one given below because that's how I learn a few years ago.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class test extends Application {
    int c=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Demo");
        Button b = new Button("Click me");
        Label l = new Label("Count=" + c);
        VBox v = new VBox(20);
        v.getChildren().addAll(b, l);
        b.setOnAction(event -> {
            c++;
            l.setText("Count=" +c);
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(v, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I have recently installed JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition 2018.1.6 and I am seeing that to open up the primaryStage window, I need to have an fxml file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Main">
</GridPane>
```

And I have to do,

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml")), 300, 300));
```

If I run the first code snippet, nothing shows up. But if I replace VBox v with FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResources("sample.fxml")), Just a window shows up without the Button and Label. **Is there a way in which I can either ignore the usage of the fxml file? Or can I, using the standard way of coding(first code snippet) and let the compiler change that into fxml format for me?**

That's because I want to have 100x100 labels in a grid layout, when each Label is one pixel. Hence, in code, it's easy to run nested for loops to initiatialize and address each Label using 2-d Array. But initializing 1000 labels inside the fxml is too lengthy, exhausting and illogical.

I never had to do such things in JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.0.2. When I upgraded to Ultimate Edition 2018.1.6, I'm getting these errors.

Comment: If your IDE forces you to do it from fxml, stop using this IDE and use a better one instead. Using fxml is an option, not a necessity. In some cases using a fxml is simply not a good option and if your fxml would end up with > 10000 elements, it's not a good idea to use fxml. The compiler is not able to produce fxml output since it's purpose is creating `.class` files. Furthermore I don't know any tool for converting java code to fxml (which often is not even possible; e.g. there's no equivalent to loops in fxml).

Comment: That's sad, because I find IntelliJ >> NetBeans > Eclipse >> BlueJ. IntelliJ is the FASTEST way to code. I got the ultimate edition to access the Java EE and database plugins, but now I see that it cannot run a JavaFx program without fxml file. By the way, Thanks.

Comment: @61KeystoMusic - Now you see wrong. :) IntelliJ DOES allow you to create any type of JavaFX program, either with FXML or code or a mixture of both.  The SAMPLE template for a JavaFX application in IntelliJ is just that, a sample. You can change it however you wish.

Comment: Have you actually TRIED using your first code snippet in IntelliJ before asking this question and concluding it can't be done?

Comment: Yes of course, I have tried it. I just restarted my computer and then made a normal Java Application and then put in the JavaFx code without fxml file. Somehow it worked. I think the window kept crashing everytime I run. I seriously don't know what was the problem? I wrote the exact as code as snippet #1 both times. Anyways, it's working now so no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use IntelliJ with JavaFX without FXML.

**Q: Is there a way in which I can either ignore the usage of the fxml file?**

**A:** Considering your code snippet you refer on default setup you get from IntelliJ when you create new JavaFX project, yes their default setup uses `.fxml` but it isn't required to use it. You can delete that `sample.fxml` file and rewrite `start` as you want.

**Side note:** Nothing prevents you to use both fxml and code approach in same project, in some cases using fxml is better approach while in some other situations it is better to use code.

**Q: Or can I, using the standard way of coding(first code snippet) and let the compiler change that into fxml format for me?**

**A:** There is no way to convert Java code to `fxml`, but as I already said it is up to you to decide which one to use, and you can even uses both of them in same project.

Comment: No problem, if this solves your question mark it as solution so people know that your question is solved.